# Is there way to find out why response data is not push to the entities array using Redux Toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Currently I'am studying redux toolkit and my module is to fetch or get the authenticated users details after I got the details I want to insert it to the state. However my entity rejected I don't know the right term for that. There is no error found the main problem is the response data is not inserting to the entity array.

My goal: after submitting the button I want to set the response data to the state

**UserSlice:**

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createEntityAdapter, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import api from '../services/api';

const LoginAdapter = createEntityAdapter()

export const LoginAuthentication = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/login',
  async ({inp_email, inp_password}, {rejectWithValue, dispatch}) => {
    await api.post('/auth/login',{
      email: inp_email,
      password: inp_password,
      session: '1'
    }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data.data.json())
      return response.data.data;
    }).catch(function (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data?.message)
    });
  }
)

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name:"user",
    initialState: LoginAdapter.getInitialState({
      isLoading: false,
    }),
    extraReducers: {
      [LoginAuthentication.pending](state, action){
        state.isLoading = true
      },
      [LoginAuthentication.fulfilled](state, {payload}){
        state.isLoading = false
        LoginAdapter.setAll(state, payload)
      },
      [LoginAuthentication.rejected](state, action) {
        state.isLoading = false
      }
    }
})

export const { login, logout, loginError } = userSlice.actions;
export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.login;
export const selectUserErrorMess = (state) => state.user.loginError;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

**Here is the sample inspector redux state:**

[image: Sample Inspector]

Answer (score 0):

The real issue here is that something went wrong with the API call, causing your code to step into the `catch` clause and do `return rejectWithValue()`.  As a result, the `.fulfilled` reducer case never ran.

Check your network tab or try logging that error value to see what the actual problem is.

Comment: I got an error says that Cannot convert undefined or null to object on this line  LoginAdapter.setAll(state, payload)

Comment: Then the problem is probably that `response.data.data` is not a correct value to return, or that the contents you expect to be there are missing.  So, when the adapter tries to process `action.payload`, you're giving it an empty value.

Comment: yes mark your correct when i try to console log the action payload it gives undefined. so why those happen, But I have a response on my api.

Comment: Well, it's _your_ app, _your_ API response, and _your_ extraction code :) So, look at what the server is actually sending back in the response, and how your code is handling that.